# left -join-on-concat-fields

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to join (required to use join) these 2 tables table and table B.

I have table A

| CoverID |
| --- |
| 4!12569 |
| 3!18175 |
| 1!478931 |

And Table B

| ID | Accountid |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 12569 |
| 3 | 18175 |
| 1 | 478931 |

Please advise how can I join the table using concat

Comment: Using `CONCAT` in a `JOIN` is no different to how you would normally use `CONCAT`: `CONCAT(Param1, Param2[, Param3..., ParamN])` Where, exactly, are you stuck in this problem? The real problem, however, is that you need to use `CONCAT`, rather than having the data properly separated (into 2 columns) in your table `A`.

Comment: Your bigger issue is that table `A` violates the basic principles of database normalisation by combining discrete properties in a single column, this is going to always cause you implementation and performance issues.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.CoverID = CONCAT(B.ID, '!', B.Accountid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
From TableA A
Left join TableB B
On A.CoverId = (concat(B.ID, ‘!’, B.AccountId))
```

You need to make sure the data types match. So you’ll have to play around with whether or not you need to cast the data to match within the concatenation besides that it should work.